# CSS only scroll snap in iOS

Tags: ios, css, flexbox, scroll-snap-points

I am trying to achieve CSS only scroll-snap behaviour in an app but see that **it doesn't work as expected in iOS**. Here is link to [CodePen](https://codepen.io/servernoj/pen/VgBqPB) that demo the case.

The code is enclosed below

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.panel-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  border: 2px solid lightgray;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
  scroll-snap-type: mandatory;
  scroll-snap-points-x: repeat(100%);
  scroll-snap-destination: 0 0;
}
.panel {
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  border: 2px solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.one {
  border-color: red;
}
.two {
  border-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel-container">
  <div class="panel one">
    One
  </div>
  <div class="panel two">
    Two
  </div>
</div>
```

I included a few redundant CSS rules that I've learned in corresponding MDN page, nut I also tried without them with no luck.

I suspect that there the issue is caused because of combination of `flex` and `scroll-snap` but I'm not sure that it is the case.

PS: There are a few threads in SO discussing scroll-snap issues. One of them [combines JS + CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52989070/css-scroll-snap-visual-glitches-on-ios-when-programmatically-setting-style-on) which is not exactly what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 5):

The container needs `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch` and the children `overflow:visible` (which they already have in your case).

Comment: -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch,  working perfectly but removing the default scrollbar, is there any way to get that scrollbar?

Comment: @Atul No I did not find a way, this is probably the best we get. A little scroll animation or cut off shadow might help.

Comment: Adding the -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch helped me to fix scrolling in iOS/Safari 12 and lower. Thanks.